# Detecting if an intent goes unreceived

Tags: android, null, android-intent

I don't have an IDE in front of me, but what happens when an intent fires, but it's target is such that it doesn't exist on the phone.  Like, say a public API from a third party app.  But thats not really guaranteed to be installed.

Will it force close, ignore it, have some sort of callback that it wasn't received by anything...?

Just curious on the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If intent was sent via `startActivity`, `startActivities` or `startActivityForResult` an `ActivityNotFound` exception is thrown.

If intent was sent via `startService` then nothing bad happens, and `startService` just returns `null`. And if `bindService` is used, function returns `false`.